# Python multiple class inherit: invoke the variable of a son class

Tags: python

It's a simple example.

```
class p1:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
class p2:
    def __init__(self,y):
        self.y=y

class son(p1,p2):
    def pp(self):
        print(self.p2.y)

c=son(p1(1),p2(2))
c.pp()
```

Now the `son` class has inherited `p1` and `p2`. How can I can execute `son().pp`?

Comment: Your second last line calls the constructor of `son`, which shoul be defined as `__init__`. I think you're looking for the `super` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P1 and p2 are not variables you can access like that. They are classes. The class syntax (though it's exactly the same as function call syntax) doesn't add P1, p2 as variables for you to use.

What you're looking for is the super() function.
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function